# Is it possible to check whether the connection to a SQL database exists before opening the connection?

Tags: c#, sql

Is it possible to check if there is a connection to a SQL database exists before opening a new connection?

Comment: How can a connection "exist" before you open it?

Answer (score 0):

thats why connection pooling is exists for. he checks it and if not - he re-open it.

also you can check it in the web.config for existing entry,.

Comment: The web.config will tell you the definition of a connection, but it won't have anything to say about whether there is an open connection or not.

Comment: @jon he didnt want to see if the conenction is open or not. he wants to check if exists

Answer (score 0):

Create a method with try catch block. Try connects and returns true, catch returns false. You could even set a shorter timeout so you aren't waiting 90 seconds.